# How can I change the caption and tooltip of the Debug.Start command buttons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ui-automation, vsix, vs-extensibility

With reference to the screen dump further down.

I wrote a visual studio extension that automates the complicated build process at my current company, and also allow our developers to build scenarios that they can run to start the system in a specific state on any screen to save time that is normally wasted on the application flow to get to the screen that is currently developed or debugged.

Up to now I had a separate RUN / START button that shows either (1) Scenario if you selected a scenario, or (2) XXX System if you didn't select a scenario and the system itself will be started without any setup or intercepts.

But I realized that it is not correct or natural for the visual studio IDE to have another START button.

How can I "override" the caption and tooltip of the Visual Studio IDE "Debug.Start" command to resemble the start button inside my extension? Obviously I will only do this when the developer actually have one of the company projects open. Otherwise I'll just leave the visual studio IDE as it is.

[image]